# when are graded injective modules graded and injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, injective-module, graded-modules

Define a graded injective module over a graded ring $R$ to be an injective object in $GrMod-R$ (the category of right graded $R$-modules). From the little research I have done, a graded injective module is not necessarily injective. However, if it is graded and injective then it is graded injective.

**Question** Under what conditions on $R$, the graded injective modules are exactly the modules that are graded and injective?

I know that the latter always holds for graded projectives. Probably my question holds for Artin rings, or perhaps fd algebras (?), but I can't find a reference in the literature ,nor I can prove it...